# Using Action Bar Home Button as an anchor view for PopupMenu

Tags: android

Is it possible to have Home button to trigger a PopupMenu? The following code would not work since the action view has not been set up.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
case android.R.id.home:
       PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(JournalList.this, item.getActionView());
       popup.inflate(R.menu.list_select_menu);
   popup.show();
}
```

The home button is not available to be accessed this following way either, the findItem fails to find the menu item:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   Button img = new Button(this);
   img.setText("Pop");
   menu.findItem(android.R.id.home).setActionView(someImageButton);
}
```

So what part of ActionBar Home button can be used as an anchor view or if there's a way to set up the view first?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you have no good way of getting at the home button, and so you cannot use it as an anchor for a `PopupMenu`. Consider instead using `NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST` with the `ActionBar`, which puts a `Spinner` to the right of the home button and caption, where you supply the `SpinnerAdapter`.

Comment: AstridTask app seems to be able to make use the home button or maybe its nav bar is completely customized somehow. I've used the spinner you mentioned but I think the home button is intuitive for providing users with help, about, etc in addition to the spinner - like the use of OSX's apple icon.

Comment: @achristoph: What you think is intuitive will run counter to what millions of Android users will think is intuitive. Those users will be using other apps that adhere to [the Android design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html) and will wonder why your app does not behave the way the other apps do. Don't use the action bar if you are not going to follow the established patterns for the action bar -- roll something else yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a 0px top-left most anchor view to your root viewgroup,

and use this view as the PopupMenu anchor view.

I think this is the most simple way.

Answer (score 1):

just replace

```
       PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(JournalList.this, item.getActionView());
```

to this

```
       PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(JournalList.this, findViewById(item.getItemId()));
```